# Execute html at a certain time

Tags: html, time

I am wondering how you execute html on a certain time. I have a small marquee html code that I want to be executed at the time I want, instead of just immediately once the page loads.

Comment: HTML code does not execute, it gets rendered.

Comment: At a specific time or relative to page load ? You can use the Date object in javascript to get date/time. What have you tried and what is the specific problem ?

Comment: Well I have a Marquee code that I want to slide in at the bottom of my page , but I don't want it to do it immediently after the page loads.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I stand corected

Answer (score 1):

Html does not execute, but it renders.

For execution, you need a script or program. For client side, you should use javascipt. Many people use a library that generally improves their code, and makes programming easier. I would recommend jQuery, but there are others.

To do what you are asking in jQuery is trivial, you would use `setTimeout` to calculate the time you want it to execute, and then insert or display the html code in the timeout callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use *[jquery's marquee plugin](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)* to access your *`marquee`* in an easy way.
Then, the *`HTML`* is not executable! You should create a client-side script to achieve your purpose. For example: after adding a reference to *`jquery.js`* and *`marquee.jquery.js`* in your page, try:

**HTML:**

```
<marquee id="myMarq">Content here...</marquee>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myMarq").marquee().trigger('stop');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#myMarq").marquee().trigger('start');
    },10000 /* or any time-out you want, in milisecond */);
});
```